# Dirac delta function composition rule

Tags: mathematical-physics, dirac-delta

after reviewing the properties of the Dirac delta function, I have a hard time figuring out one property: the composition rule.

[Composition rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0ZMf.png)

I understand the integral form comes from a change of variable and by partitioning the domain around the roots of a function g, but I don't understand the first form.

Comment: What is "the integral form"? There's no integral in the image you link to. And what is "the first form"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $f(x_i) = 0$ with $f'(x_i) > 0.$ Then there is some interval $(x_i-\epsilon, x_i+\epsilon)$ on which $f'>0$ and $f$ is invertible. Then, using the substituion $y = f(x),\ dy = f'(x) \, dx,$
$$\begin{align}
\int_{x_i-\epsilon}^{x_i+\epsilon} \delta(f(x)) \, \varphi(x) \, dx 
= \int_{f(x_i-\epsilon)}^{f(x_i+\epsilon)} \delta(y) \, \varphi(f^{-1}(y)) \, \frac{dy}{f'(f^{-1}(y))} \\
= \varphi(f^{-1}(0)) \, \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(0))} 
= \varphi(x_i) \, \frac{1}{f'(x_i)} \\
= \frac{1}{f'(x_i)} \int_{x_i-\epsilon}^{x_i+\epsilon} \delta(x-x_i)\,\varphi(x)\,dx\\
= \int_{x_i-\epsilon}^{x_i+\epsilon} \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{f'(x_i)} \,\varphi(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$

If instead $f'(x_i) < 0,$ then $f(x_i-\epsilon) > f(x_i+\epsilon)$ and we get
$$\begin{align}
\int_{x_i-\epsilon}^{x_i+\epsilon} \delta(f(x)) \, \varphi(x) \, dx 
= \int_{f(x_i-\epsilon)}^{f(x_i+\epsilon)} \delta(y) \, \varphi(f^{-1}(y)) \, \frac{dy}{f'(f^{-1}(y))} \\
= \{ \text{ swapping integration limits } \} \\
= - \int^{f(x_i-\epsilon)}_{f(x_i+\epsilon)} \delta(y) \, \varphi(f^{-1}(y)) \, \frac{dy}{f'(f^{-1}(y))} \\
= - \varphi(f^{-1}(0)) \, \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(0))} 
= - \varphi(x_i) \, \frac{1}{f'(x_i)} \\
= - \frac{1}{f'(x_i)} \int_{x_i-\epsilon}^{x_i+\epsilon} \delta(x-x_i)\,\varphi(x)\,dx\\
= - \int_{x_i-\epsilon}^{x_i+\epsilon} \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{f'(x_i)} \,\varphi(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$

The two cases can be combined into
$$
\int_{x_i-\epsilon}^{x_i+\epsilon} \delta(f(x)) \, \varphi(x) \, dx 
= \int_{x_i-\epsilon}^{x_i+\epsilon} \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|} \,\varphi(x)\,dx
$$

Taking all zeroes into account we get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(f(x)) \, \varphi(x) \, dx 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_i \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|} \,\varphi(x)\,dx
,
$$
i.e.
$$
\delta(f(x))
= \sum_i \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}
.
$$