# An identity which is involved with dirac delta function.

Tags: calculus, integration, dirac-delta

I was spending more time to find a way to solve this identity. However, I still couldn't figure it out. The identity that I need to prove is:
$$\delta (g(x))=  \sum_a  \frac{ \delta (x-a)}{|g'(a)|}$$
Where $g(a) = 0$ and $g'(a)\neq0$.

I appriciate if someone can help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: That is a definition of the Dirac Delta distribution composed with a smooth function.  One does not derive this.  However, if one proceed heuristicaly with a change of variable, it is straightforward to arrive at the result.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3557440/168433

Comment: @MarkViola I don't agree that this is just a definition. I would instead define the composition of the distribution $u$ with the function $g$ (having some requirements) by 
$$
\langle u\circ g, \phi \rangle 
= \langle \frac{1}{g'\circ g^{-1}} u, \phi\circ g^{-1} \rangle
$$
based on
$$
\int u(g(x)) \, \phi(x) \, dx
= \int u(y) \, \phi(g^{-1}(y)) \, \frac{dy}{g'(g^{-1}(y))}
.
$$

Comment: @md2perpe I stated that one can heuristically apply a change of variable to arrive at the result.  But the composite you wrote is indeed a definition.  And for $u=\delta$, the equivalence is easy to establish.